# prevent auto adding port to the url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I FTP'd my local Wordpress installation to a HostMonster.

I've created a subdomain called 'blog' for the installation on HostMonster.

For some reason, when I enter `{website_url}/blog`, the site goes to `{website_url}:8080/blog`.

It adds the localhost port number 8080 (which is my wampserver localhost address) to the url and does not display the web-based blog.

I did some research and modified the 'hosts' file in the `System32/Drivers/ect` folder to add the IP address of the website to no avail.

I'm still getting the same result...no webpage displayed, 404 city.

Does anyone know what the issues are here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions to change WordPress URL by **Wordpress.org**

**[Changing The Site URL « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_Site_URL)**

Answer (score 0):

Set your siteurl and home options to remove the :8080 part and have a try again.

Check the options in the admin panel:

Settings -> General -> WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL)

Or you can change the `wp_options` table in mysql, change the field `siteurl` and `home`

Comment: I edited the wp-config.php file by adding <code>define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');</code>

Comment: Could not get to the website so I can't get to the settings because the page won't load.  I did check the database settings in mysqladmin in HostMonster and the 'SiteURL' and 'HOME' values were already set as 'blog.{site}.com.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I'm still searching for a solution.

Comment: @hutchback Thanks for helping hutchback and fish_ball, but I'm still looking for a solution. I should add that I have another Wordpress install in the root and this is a second Wordpress install for the blog section of the site.  You think I need to do a multisite or something else?

Comment: It's working now.  I think the database modification worked.  I had to wait for the changes to take effect.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Now it's not working.  This is weird.  It was working one minute, now it's not.